# R - Find correlation between multiple rows considering overlapping dates

Tags: r, data.table, correlation

I have a data table with rainfall measurements from several rain gauges. This is a sample of my dataset:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/yub3db3739d80h2/dat.csv?dl=1")
> dat
         ID       date value
    1:  937 2000-01-01  14.2
    2:  937 2000-01-02  68.3
    3:  937 2000-01-03  28.4
    4:  937 2000-01-04  30.2
    5:  937 2000-01-05  12.8
   ---                      
33905: 1600 2017-06-12   0.1
33906: 1600 2017-06-13  36.1
33907: 1600 2017-06-14   0.3
33908: 1600 2017-06-15   0.0
33909: 1600 2017-06-16   0.0
```

I also have a data table with each gauge's ID along with the ID's of the nearest few gauges, as well as the common dates they have of rainfall measurements:

```
neighbors <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/phhskbhxsxmrxy1/neighbours.csv?dl=1")
> neighbors
      ID ID_nearest common_date_begin common_date_end diff_days
 1:    1       1117        2000-03-01      2006-12-03      2468
 2:    1        920        2000-03-01      2004-11-04      1709
 3: 1000         48        2000-03-01      2006-12-03      2468
 4: 1000       1600        2000-03-01      2017-06-16      6316
 5: 1000        937        2000-03-01      2017-01-22      6171
 6: 1001        352        2007-07-10      2017-06-16      3629
 7: 1001        324        2007-07-10      2017-06-16      3629
 8: 1002       1338        2006-01-01      2017-06-16      4184
 9: 1002        412        2006-01-01      2009-07-12      1288
10: 1002       1330        2006-01-01      2017-06-16      4184
11: 1002       1349        2006-01-01      2017-06-16      4184
12: 1009        801        2006-01-01      2017-01-22      4039
```

For example, gauge ID `1` has two close neighbors: ID's `1117` and `920`. The overlapping measurement period for stations `1` and `1117` goes from March 01, 2000 to December 03, 2006.

For each combination like this in `neighbors`, I need to calculate the correlation of the rainfall measurements between the main and the surrounding gauges within the overlapping dates.

For example, the correlation for the first pair would be calculated like this:

```
cor(dat[ID==1 & date %between% c("2000-03-01", "2006-12-03")]$value,
    dat[ID==1117 & date %between% c("2000-03-01", "2006-12-03")]$value)

cor(dat[ID==1 & date %between% c("2000-03-01", "2004-11-04")]$value,
    dat[ID==920 & date %between% c("2000-03-01", "2004-11-04")]$value)
```

And the expected output would be something like this:

```
  ID ID_nearest correlation    n
   1       1117        0.55 2468
   1        920        0.48 1709
1000         48        0.77 2468
1000       1600        0.52 6316
1000        937        0.84 6171
```

and so on for each `ID` in `neighbors`.

But I am having a hard time coming up with a programmatic way to achieve this.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not a loop?

Comment: @nigelhenry because typically, they are very slow and inefficient in R.

Comment: ...but yet you accept the answer with a straightforward loop

Comment: Well it's the answer that actually works, and I really need this analysis done to go on with my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/yub3db3739d80h2/dat.csv?dl=1")
neighbors <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/phhskbhxsxmrxy1/neighbours.csv?dl=1")

results <- neighbors[, -c(3:4)]

i <- as.numeric(neighbors[1, 1])

correlations <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(neighbors), ncol =1)

ids <- unique(neighbors$ID)

x <- 1

for (i in ids) {

  temp <- neighbors[ID==i]

  for (id in 1:nrow(temp)){

    near_id <- as.numeric(temp[id, 2])

    beg_date <- temp[id, 3]

    end_date <- temp[id, 4]

    correlations[x,1] <- cor(dat[ID==i & date %between% c(beg_date, end_date)]$value,
          dat[ID==near_id & date %between% c(beg_date, end_date)]$value)

    x <- x + 1
  }

}

results <- cbind(results[, 1], results[, 2], correlations, results[, 3])

colnames(results) <- c("ID", "ID_nearest", "correlation", "n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I get the following error during the loop: `Error in .prepareFastSubset(isub = isub, x = x, enclos = parent.frame(),  : 
  RHS of == is length 5 which is not 1 or nrow (12). For robustness, no recycling is allowed (other than of length 1 RHS). Consider %in% instead.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (neighbors[loop, ] != i) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (neighbors[loop, ] != i) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: loop works for the subset of data you've given here. I'll need to have access to the full data to debug the error

Comment: I beg to differ. I get the error just after loading the data with `library(data.table) dat <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/yub3db3739d80h2/dat.csv?dl=1") neighbors <- fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/phhskbhxsxmrxy1/neighbours.csv?dl=1")`. Perhaps you've made any changes to the data variables before running your code?

Comment: You were right, I've edited my answer. It works now.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! A bit slow, but definitely yields the output I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it

```
> df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(neighbors$ID), function(id) {
    d <- neighbors[neighbors[, "ID"] %in% id, ]
    main.vals <- dat %>%
        dplyr::filter(ID == id & (date >= d$common_date_begin & date <= max(d$common_date_end))) %>%
        dplyr::select(value)
    main.vals <- main.vals$value
    nearest.vals <- lapply(unique(d$ID_nearest), function(neigh.id) {
        r <- d[d$ID_nearest== neigh.id, ]
        vals <- dat[dat$ID == neigh.id & (dat$date >= r$common_date_begin & dat$date <= r$common_date_end), ]
        return (vals$value)
    })
    d <- d %>%
        dplyr::select(-c(common_date_begin, common_date_end)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(correlation = sapply(nearest.vals, cor, y = main.vals),
                      n = diff_days)    
    return(d)
}))
> df
#   ID ID_nearest diff_days correlation    n
# 1  1       1117      2468    0.527024 2468
# 2  1        920      1709   -0.469635 1709
```

where we loop over each unique `ID` in the neighbor data, filter out its values from the `dat` date.frame, subsequently filter out the values for each neighbour in the `neighbors` data.frame, and check the correlation between the rainfall of correponding to the main id and each neighbor id.

I used the following data (modified to add the `ID_nearest` values to `dat`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

dat <- read.table(text = "
    1   2000-03-01  55.3
    1   2000-03-02  55.6
    1   2005-03-03  48.3
    920 2000-03-01  14.2
    920 2000-04-02  68.3
    920 2000-04-03  68.4
    1117 2003-03-01   0.1
    1117 2003-06-13  36.1
    1117 2003-06-14   0.3
", col.names = c("ID", "date", "value"))
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date)

neighbors <- read.table(text = "
  ID ID_nearest common_date_begin common_date_end diff_days
   1       1117        2000-03-01      2006-12-03      2468
   1        920        2000-03-01      2004-11-04      1709
", header = TRUE)
neighbors$common_date_begin <- as.POSIXct(neighbors$common_date_begin)
neighbors$common_date_end <- as.POSIXct(neighbors$common_date_end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try first:

```
DT <- rnfl[neighbors, on=.(ID, date>=common_date_begin, date<=common_date_end),
    c(mget(paste0("i.", names(neighbors))), 
    by=.EACHI,
    .(date=x.date, v1=x.value))][, (1L:3L) := NULL]
setnames(DT, names(DT), gsub("i.", "", names(DT), fixed=TRUE))

DT[rnfl, on=.(ID_nearest=ID, date), v2 := value]
DT[, .(correlation=cor(v1, v2)), names(neighbors)]
```

If it is too slow, we can try another approach.

---

data and also from prev qn:

```
library(data.table)
rnfl <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
    date=Sys.Date() + c(0:4, 2:6),
    value=c(17.6, 5.6, 4.5, 8.3, 11.7, 10.7, 15.6, 11.6, 8.3, 2.3))
near <- data.table(ID=1, ID_nearest=2)

summ <- rnfl[, .(startdate=date[1L], enddate=date[.N]),
    .(ID, g=cumsum(c(0L, diff(date)!=1L)))]

setkey(summ, startdate, enddate)
olap <- unique(foverlaps(summ, summ)[ID!=i.ID, .(
    ID1=pmin(ID, i.ID),
    ID2=pmax(ID, i.ID),
    common_date_begin=pmax(startdate, i.startdate),
    common_date_end=pmin(enddate, i.enddate))])

near[, c("ID1", "ID2") := .(pmin(ID, ID_nearest), pmax(ID, ID_nearest))]

cols <- c("common_date_begin", "common_date_end")
neighbors <- near[olap, on=.(ID1, ID2), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))][,
    n := as.integer(common_date_end - common_date_begin)]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping again! Right in the first line, with my real data, I got the same error as before: `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 9024561 rows; more than 8660131 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE.`

Comment: I know! My dataset is challenging even for `data.table`! If you have access to your hotmail account, I can definitely send you the file instead of Dropbox...

Comment: its a memory issue and I dont think its because of `data.table`. I added another approach.

Comment: Nada. Got the same error message after each step :(.

Comment: @thiagoveloso, your rnfl.csv does not have value column. i added `by=.EACHI` in the first attempt as per the error message.

Comment: I am so sorry. I've sent the correct version now. I had already tried `by=.EACHI` to no avail. My dataset really has a large number of duplicated entries. This is probably what's causing the error, even on a machine with 32 GB RAM.

Comment: I created random numbers for values just now and it works fine

Comment: And I only had a 16gb ram